# Auto-Centered Fluid-Width TabPanels with Max-Width Limit

Tags: centering, tabpanel, css, spry

I'm trying to create a Tab Panel that auto adjusts to fit the width of each of the tab content boxes, & also has a Max-Width of 900px, & also stays auto centered on the screen. I can get them to work individually, but not all 3 together.

You can see at this webpage that I've got the Max-Width: 900px working & the Auto-Centering working, but not Fluid-Width Auto-Adjust (it always stays at 900px instead of reducing its width for the slimmer tab content boxes, see the tabs "WATCH THE FILM" & "SCREENINGS" specifically): http://www.shellshockeddoc.com/

Here is my CSS for the tab content group so far:

```
#TabbedPanels2 .TabbedPanelsContentGroup {
max-width:900px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
margin-top:105px;
}
```

& here is the HTML:

```
<div id="TabbedPanels2">
<h2 align="center">TAB HEADLINE 1</h2>
<p align="center">Tab Content 1. This tab contains content about 850px wide.</p>

<h2 align="center" >TAB HEADLINE 2</h2>
<p align="center">Tab Content 2. This tab contains content about 350px wide.</p>
etc
</div>
```

Thanks a lot in advance! I'm pretty new to CSS & appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: #TabbedPanels2 .TabbedPanelsTabGroup has a width set of 700px. It will stay at 700px. Try width: 100%

Comment: Thanks! #TabbedPanels2 .TabbedPanelsTabGroup only deals with the actual tabs. Those are working ok. I'm having trouble with the content boxes. I want them to automatically resize to fit the content in each box, while never surpassing 900px & also staying in the center of the pages.